# A little note to our wonderful community

Tags: discussion, status-planned

Dear Software Recommendations community and fellow moderators,

I want to take a quick moment to let everyone know that I'm going to be volunteering less time here.

We have a great community, and I appreciate every one of you.

I'm just not getting much out of being a moderator, and it is taking up quite a bit of my free time.  I also feel a fair amount of pressure to visit our community frequently to keep spam at bay and take care of any pressing issues.

I will continue to volunteer and perform my moderation duties, but I'm going to be spending less of my scarce free time doing these things.

Thank you all for being wonderful people and for being willing to share your wealth of knowledge with others.

My best regards,

*RockPaperLizard*

Answer (score 3):

Your contributions to this site are great, so thanks a lot for everything so far!

Getting busy with life is very understandable.

Anyway, glad to hear that you will still be not too far away :-)

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, and you're most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This Stack Exchange website is one of the best-moderated websites in the Stack Exchange network. Thanks for the great moderation!

Comment: Thank you Franck, and you're welcome.  One of the primary reasons this community is so great is because of people like you.  I only have good things to say about everyone here, and that's quite remarkable given the number of people in our community.  Often, a community has a few bad seeds that ruin it for everyone, but here every single person is sprouting gorgeous sunflowers.